VBA-Excel - Variable in Cells.Find Issue
I Have declared the x variable and populated the array
But this code doesn't work? I need to find 200 variables like "Name=AssyNumber"
Where AssyNumber is a text inside the SetSpNameDataFields array but There are 200 different values to find.
For x = 1 To 200
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="Name=" + SetSpNameDataFields(x), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.Select
    SP_Data(x) = Mid(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 7, 100)
Next


"Doesn't work" means what, specifically?

What:="Name=" + SetSpNameDataFields(x); we don't know what is in SetSpNameDataFields and the use of + rather than & may be problematic.

Additionally:  Avoid select/activate

If you're searching a single column then Application.Match would be faster than Find

Couple quick changes:
'SetSpNameDataFields = ??? 'Are there 200 entries to this?
For x = 1 To 200
    Dim foundRng as Range:  Set foundRng = Cells.Find(What:="Name=" & SetSpNameDataFields(x), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not foundRng is Nothing then
        SP_Data(x) = Mid(foundRng.Offset(1, 0).Value, 7, 100)
    Else
        MsgBox "foundRng not found."
    End if
Next


Using the Find Method
' Your preceding code...

' Assuming 'SetSpNameDataFields' is a 1D array.
Dim SP_Data() As Variant:
ReDim SP_Data(LBound(SetSpNameDataFields) To UBound(SetSpNameDataFields))

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!

With ws.UsedRange
' To improve efficiency, make the range as small as possible:
' - if it's a single column, use e.g. 'ws.Columns("A")'
' - if it's a single row, use e.g. 'ws.Rows(1)'
    
    Dim lcell As Range: Set lcell = .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge)
    
    Dim cell As Range, x As Long
    
    For x = LBound(SetSpNameDataFields) To UBound(SetSpNameDataFields)
        Set cell = .Find(What:="Name=" & SetSpNameDataFields(x), _
            After:=lcell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
            ' 'xlNext, False, False' are default arguments
        If Not cell Is Nothing Then ' was found
            SP_Data(x) = Mid(cell.Offset(1, 0).Value, 7, 100) ' below?
        'Else ' was not found; keep it empty
        End If
    Next x

End With

